# jQuery showing the value of previous entered valu not the selected one

Tags: php, jquery

I have made a small application on a school. Where there is a `dropdown field`. In that `dropdown` I have all the `students name` and there are also 4 remaining input fields. where the input fields will have values for marks like `marks in physics, chemistry, maths` and the last one will make the `total` and that will be `addition of marks in physics+chemistry+maths.`
  Now I have used some `ajax and jquery tricks` and have done some changes like when one `student name will be selected from the dropdown box it will show the mark for that particular student` in physics, chemistry, maths. Now I want that the marks for physics, chemistry, maths will be added and will be sum in total field. For that I have written jQuery like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#student_name').on('change',function(event){
    var totalmarks = jQuery("#marks_physics").val() + jQuery("#marks_chemistry").val()+ jQuery("#marks_chemistry");
    jQuery("#marks_total").val(totalmarks);
  });
});
</script>
```

Here id `student_name` is the `dropdown field for the students name` and id `marks_total` is the field name where the `total mark` should show `after addition`. Now my problem is that it is showing the `marks` of that student when `once the name has been changed in that drop down`.
Suppose I have two students named as `A and B`. When once `A` is selected it is showing nothing but as I am selecting `B from the dropdown` it is showing the values of `A`.I had also used `select` in place of `change` but its not working there. So can someone tell me how to solve this. Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Actually it is showing the actual values of that field but when I tried the console tab to see the value of that field as `console.log(#marks_physics)` it is showing the previous value for that field and also in place of `total` it is showing the previous entered `total marks` value.

Comment: see `totalmarks` last in line `jQuery("#marks_chemistry")` you forgot `jQuery("#marks_chemistry").val()`

Comment: but where your `#marks_physics` put fiddle link so better solution

Comment: can you show your html markup plz

Comment: here is a small demo on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jLdmU/40/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#student_name').ajaxComplete(function(event,request,settings){
    var totalmarks = jQuery("#marks_physics").val() + jQuery("#marks_chemistry").val()+ jQuery("#marks_chemistry");
    jQuery("#marks_total").val(totalmarks);
  });
});
</script>
```

Now you can alert your actual entered values as `console.log(#marks_physics)` and it will show you the right one.